# OpenGL/LWJGL how to keep a object in the middle of the screen when moving the camera

Tags: java, opengl, camera, lwjgl

So I am trying to make a game with LWJGL 3 in Java. And I want to always keep the Player Object in the middle of the screen while moving the camera.

But I have problems doing that.

I tried to just set the position of camera to the player position but this doesn't work that well.
It dose move the player when the camera moves, however it doesn't move enough to keep the player in the middle.

This is my code :

```
public class Player extends Texture {

Camera camera;

public Player(Vector3f position, Vector3f rotation, Camera camera) {
    super("/resources/textures/entities/Player.png", position, rotation, new Vector3f(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.1f));
    this.camera = camera;
}

public void update() {
    Vector3f camPos = camera.getPosition();
    // set x and y from camera to player
    this.getGameObject().getPosition().x = camPos.x;
    this.getGameObject().getPosition().y = camPos.y;
    }
}
```

My camera update method looks like this :

```
public void update() {
    if (Input.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_A)) {
        this.position.x -= movementSpeed * Engine.delta;
    }
    if (Input.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_D)) {
        this.position.x += movementSpeed * Engine.delta;
    }
    if (Input.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_W)) {
        this.position.y += movementSpeed * Engine.delta;
    }
    if (Input.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_S)) {
        this.position.y -= movementSpeed * Engine.delta;
    }

    if (Input.isScrollingUp()) {
        this.position.z -= movementSpeed * ZOOM_MULTIPLIER * Engine.delta;
        if (this.position.z < MIN_Z) {
            this.position.z = MIN_Z;
        }
    }
    if (Input.isScrollingDown()) {
        this.position.z += movementSpeed * ZOOM_MULTIPLIER * Engine.delta;
        if (this.position.z > MAX_Z) {
            this.position.z = MAX_Z;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think there is something wrong with the camera update method but if it helps .

So yeah I tried a bit more but that worked even worse so please help me I can't find a solution.

Edit :

Here is my code for the renderer I however have only a vague idea how it works because I flowed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLaWuTOi9sDeomi2umQ7N8Lqs-GtE1H4-b) where this part wasn't explained that well. The source code for the Matrixf4 Class is [here](https://github.com/CodingAP/lwjgl3-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial12/src/engine/maths/Matrix4f.java) from the tutorial guy :

```
public void renderObject(GameObject object, Camera camera) {
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(object.getMesh().getVAO());
    GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object.getMesh().getIBO());
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL13.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, object.getMesh().getMaterial().getTextureID());
    shader.bind();
    shader.setUniform("model", Matrix4f.transform(object.getPosition(), object.getRotation(), object.getScale()));
    shader.setUniform("view", Matrix4f.view(camera.getPosition(), camera.getRotation()));
    shader.setUniform("projection", window.getProjection());
    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, object.getMesh().getIndices().length, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    shader.unbind();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

The window.getProjection() just returns this :

```
Matrix4f.projection(70.0f, (float)width / (float) height, 0.01f, 5000.0f);
```

The first value is the fov, The second is the aspect ration and the last two are how near and far something can be until it won't be rendered anymore.

Edit 2 :

What I think is important is the scale variable because it scales the whole Mesh down so it doesn't cover the full screen.

Edit 3 :

Found out that the scale was the problem.

I just had to divide the cam position by the scale in the Player class:

```
public void update() {
    Vector3f camPos = camera.getPosition();
    this.getGameObject().getPosition().x = camPos.x / this.getGameObject().getScale().x;
    this.getGameObject().getPosition().y = camPos.y / this.getGameObject().getScale().y;
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 ok added some code hope this helps to find the answer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 The rotation is just a Vector3f So no Euler angles. But is the rotation relay important ? The Texture is 2D But is rendered in 3D so I can do some 3D things in the future.

Comment: @Rabbid76 [Here](https://github.com/CodingAP/lwjgl3-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial12/src/engine/maths/Matrix4f.java) thats the code for the Martixf4 class from the tutorial guy.

Comment: @Rabbid76 you know that I want to move the camera and the player at the same time in the same direction so not that the cam moves but the player doesn't and it just looks to the side to get it into view. I hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes the Matrix4f is just from the tutorial however I fixed the issue The Problem was with the scale variable. I updated my Question if you want to see how I did it. Relay easy fix but yeah sometimes you just need to take a step back and then try again. But thanks for trying to help me anyway I relay appreciate that .

Comment: Sorry, but the matrix library from that tutorial is mess. Change `result = Matrix4f.multiply(translationMatrix, Matrix4f.multiply(rotationMatrix, scaleMatrix));` to  `result = Matrix4f.multiply(scaleMatrix, Matrix4f.multiply(rotationMatrix, translationMatrix));`